# Adding a descriptive/commenting column on query results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to add a descriptive column at the end of my query results. For example
I have

```
SELECT sum(amount) as Balance FROM tbDebits WHERE CustomerID =@CustomerID;
```

Now if the Balance is positive I want to add another column called 'Description'
in my query results describing each result as positive or negative.
Any ideas?

Here is my original query:

```
SELECT t.CustomerID, c.name, c.Surname, (SELECT (
 (SELECT ISNULL(SUM(cashout),0)- 
                        ((select ISNULL(sum(Buyin),0) from [Transaction] where TYPE='Credit' and CustomerID=t.CustomerID )
                         + (select ISNULL(sum(Paid),0) from [Transaction] where TYPE='Credit' and CustomerID=t.CustomerID ))


FROM [transaction]
WHERE TYPE='Credit'
AND CustomerID=t.CustomerID 
)
-------------------
+
(
(SELECT ISNULL(SUM(cashout),0)
                    - (select ISNULL(sum(Paid),0) from [Transaction] where TYPE='Debit' AND Cashout>buyin and CustomerID=t.CustomerID ) 
                    +  (select ISNULL(sum(Cashout),0)- (select ISNULL(sum(PAID),0) from [Transaction] where TYPE='Debit' AND Cashout<buyin and CustomerID=t.CustomerID )
                             from [Transaction] where TYPE='Debit' AND Cashout<Buyin and CustomerID=t.CustomerID )
                    +  (select ISNULL(sum(Cashout),0)- (select ISNULL(sum(PAID),0) from [Transaction] where TYPE='Debit' AND Cashout=buyin and CustomerID=t.CustomerID )
                             from [Transaction] where TYPE='Debit' AND Cashout=Buyin and CustomerID=t.CustomerID )
FROM [Transaction]
WHERE CustomerID=t.CustomerID 
AND TYPE='Debit' 
AND Cashout>buyin )
)
--------------
-
(
select ISNULL(sum(Paid),0)
from [Transaction] 
where type='Debit Settlement'
AND CustomerID =t.CustomerID 
)
--------------
+
(
select ISNULL(sum(Paid),0)
from [Transaction] 
where type='Credit Settlement'
AND CustomerID =t.CustomerID 
)
)) as Balance  FROM [Transaction] as t
inner JOIN Customer AS c
on t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID 

GROUP BY t.CustomerID, c.name, c.Surname
```

Comment: To do this in SQL, you need a `CASE` statement.  Why are you trying to do this though - what's the point?

Comment: Just a customer requirement.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I tried to use the CASE statement I just had troubles using the 'Balance'. An example would be highly appreciated. To be honest, the 'Balance' is a result of many queries and subqueries so I was getting errors that I can't use case when I have multiple subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use OUTER APPLY when I need to manipulate the results of a SELECT.
I hope it is useful.

```
SELECT t.CustomerID,
       c.name,
       c.Surname,
       Balance.Custom,
       case
        when sum(Balance.Custom)>0 then 'positive'
        when sum(Balance.Custom)<0 then 'negative'
        else 'zero'
       end as [description]
FROM   [Transaction] AS t
       INNER JOIN Customer AS c
               ON t.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT ( (SELECT Isnull(Sum(cashout), 0) 
         - ( (SELECT Isnull(Sum(Buyin), 0)
                FROM   [Transaction]
                WHERE  TYPE = 'Credit'
                        AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID)
                + (SELECT Isnull(Sum(Paid), 0)
                FROM   [Transaction]
                WHERE  TYPE = 'Credit'
                        AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID) )
          FROM   [transaction]
            WHERE  TYPE = 'Credit'
                    AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID)
            -------------------
            + ((SELECT Isnull(Sum(cashout), 0) - (SELECT Isnull(Sum(Paid), 0)
                FROM   [Transaction]
                WHERE  TYPE = 'Debit'
                        AND Cashout     buyin
                        AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID) + (SELECT Isnull(Sum(Cashout), 0) 
            - (SELECT Isnull(Sum(PAID), 0)
                FROM   [Transaction]
                WHERE  TYPE = 'Debit'
                        AND Cashout < buyin
                        AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID)
                FROM   [Transaction]
                WHERE  TYPE = 'Debit'
                        AND Cashout < Buyin
                        AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID) + (SELECT Isnull(Sum(Cashout), 0)
             - (SELECT Isnull(Sum(PAID), 0)
                FROM   [Transaction]
                WHERE  TYPE = 'Debit'
                        AND Cashout = buyin
                        AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID)
            FROM   [Transaction]
                    WHERE  TYPE = 'Debit'
                        AND Cashout = Buyin
                        AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID)
            FROM   [Transaction]
            WHERE  CustomerID = t.CustomerID
                AND TYPE = 'Debit'
                AND Cashout     buyin)) 

          - (SELECT Isnull(Sum(Paid), 0)
            FROM   [Transaction]
            WHERE  type = 'Debit Settlement'
                AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID)
          + (SELECT Isnull(Sum(Paid), 0)
            FROM   [Transaction]
            WHERE  type = 'Credit Settlement'
                    AND CustomerID = t.CustomerID) ) AS Custom) AS Balance
GROUP  BY t.CustomerID,
          c.name,
          c.Surname
```

Answer (score 2):

You could incorporate the `CASE` part in a surrounding query. E.g.:

```
SELECT balance, CASE WHEN balance > 0 THEN 'positive!' 
                     WHEN balance < 0 THEN 'negative!' 
                     ELSE 'exactly zero' 
                END
FROM   (SELECT SUM(amount) AS balance
        FROM tbDebits 
        WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID) t;
```

**EDIT:** Adding the customer's details, as per the comment by @nectarines:

```
SELECT name, surname, balance, 
       CASE WHEN balance > 0 THEN 'positive!' 
            WHEN balance < 0 THEN 'negative!' 
            ELSE 'exactly zero' 
       END
FROM   (SELECT   customerid, name, surname,
                 SUM(amount) AS balance
        FROM     tbDebits 
        WHERE    CustomerID = @CustomerID
        GROUP BY customerid, name, surname -- note: there's only one name/surname per customerid
       ) t;
```

Comment: I used your example and it did work. However, I can't add the CustomerID, Name, Surname. Any ideas?

Comment: I'd add then to the internal query, and group by all of them

Comment: @nectarines I added an example of what I meant to my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    sum(amount) as balance,
    case
        when sum(amount)>0 then 'positive'
        when sum(amount)<0 then 'negative'
        else 'zero'
    end as description
FROM tbDebits
WHERE CustomerID=@CustomerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use WITH and CASE:

```
WITH A as (
... complex query goes here, do not include ORDER BY...
)
SELECT A.*, 
  CASE WHEN A.Balance > 0 then 'pos'
  CASE WHEN A.Balance < 0 then 'neg' else 'zero' end as Description
FROM A
ORDER BY ....
```